# Why in induction (n+1)! becomes (k+1)!a instead of (k+1+1)!?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation

I am just starting induction and I am having a problem understanding why is this possible.

Here is an example:

Prove that $3^{n} < (n + 1)!$ for $n \geq 4$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

This is how I start:

Basis case: n = 4 then $3^{4} < (4 + 1)!$ (Sparing the mental math) is true!

Then inductive hypothesis:

Assume that $3^{k} < (k + 1)!$ is true for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $k \geq 4$.

Inductive step:

if $n = k$ is true $n = k + 1$ is also true. So

$3^{k+1} = 3^{k} \cdot 3 = 3^{k} + 3^{k}$

Now I am stocked the person goes on and says:

$3^{k} \cdot 3 < (k + 1)! \cdot 3$ but why so?! should it it be $3^{k} \cdot 3 < (k + 1 + 1)!$ (aka $(k + 2)$) because we are replacing the k with $k+1$?

Comment: The point is to use the inductive hypothesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what you have to obtain ultimately. But you didn't state the inductive step correctly. It should be: ‘If $n=k$ is true, then $n=k+1$ is too’ (in other words: one case implies the next case, not the previous one).

So you make the hypothesis that for some $k\ge 4$, $3^k<(k+1)!$ and you have to deduce that $3^{k+1}<(k+2)!$. Now the inductive hypothesis implies, multiplying both sides of the inequality by $3$:
$$3^k\cdot3=3^{k+1}< (k+1)!\cdot 3$$
From $k\ge 4$, you deduce $k+2>k>3$, so 
$$3^{k+1}< (k+1)!\cdot 3<(k+1)!\cdot(k+2)=(k+2)!$$

Comment: Might sound silly, but I seriously don't understand how it comes to be, how does the inductive hypotesis tell you to multiply by a? $3^{k} \cdot 3 = 3^{k+1}$ because it's just the power you know that if k was 2 then $3^{2+1} = 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3$ thus that's why, for some k $3^{k} \cdot 3$ but not for $(k + 1)!$. Sorry not trying to be stubborn, but I really can't understand, why are we multiplying that side by 3? Or why that 3 is there on the $(k + 1)!$?

Comment: Because we have $3^k$ on the l.h.s. of the inductive hypothesis, and we want to obtain the analogous inequality for $3^{k+1}$, so how do you think we can step from $3^k$ to $3^{k+1}$?

Comment: Ahhhhh, there you go, ok, sorry for the silly question and the serious stubbornness! Although, so we are not replacing $k$ with $k + 1$ in this case because it's an inequality? Or we are is just that $3 = (k + 2)$ in this case because $k + 1 + 1$?

Comment: We just note that $3<k+2$ to end the inductive step. That said, we *start* with $k$ (inductive hypothesis) and try to arrive at the next case ($k+1$), but it's not linked to having an inequality, it's the general way to go.

Comment: Got it, thx so much!

Answer (score 2):

$3^{k} \cdot 3 < (k + 1)! \cdot 3$ must be true if you are assuming

$3^{k}  < (k + 1)! $

You are simply multiplying by three on both sides of the inequality.

Comment: How can that be possible? I think you are missunderstanding me $3^{k+1} = 3^{k} \cdot 3$ I am not multiplying both sides, and even if it was so, then it should be $9^{k} \cdot 9 < (k+2)! \cdot 3$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right! It could be writen as follows:
\begin{equation}
¿3^k < (k+1)! \implies 3^{k+1} < (k+2)!?
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
3^{k+1} = 3·3^{k} < 3·(k+1)! < (k+2)·(k+1)! = (k+2)!
\end{equation}
The last inequality is because $k\geq4$.